# How to handle exception with explicitly constructed Tasks

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a project which executes several operations in a very similar manner (subscribes to completion event, executes task, unsubscribes from the completion event and also deals with cancellation, timeouts etc) so I decided to write a utility class that handles that execution. However I came across a scenario which I don't understand and as a result have no idea how to fix.

This oversimplified code illustrates the problem:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Do();
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static async Task Do()
    {
        var task = new Task(async() => await Operation()/*this throws and terminates the application*/);

        try
        {
            await OperationExecuter.ExecuteAsync(task);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            //I expected the exception to be caught here
        }
    }


    static async Task Operation()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}

class OperationExecuter
{
    public static async Task ExecuteAsync(Task task)
    {
        task.Start();
        await task; //I expected the exception to be unwrapped and thrown here
    }
}
```

I also tried to have the task like `var task = new Task(() => Operation());` but the exception is never handled (although it doesn't terminate the application as it isn't raised in the main thread).

How would I handle the exception properly?

Changing the implementation to take an action yields to same results:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Do();
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static async Task Do()
    {
        var action = new Action(async () => await Operation() /*this throws and terminates the application*/);

        try
        {
            await OperationExecuter.ExecuteAsync(action);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            //I expected the exception to be caught here
        }
    }


    static async Task Operation()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}

class OperationExecuter
{
    public static async Task ExecuteAsync(Action action)
    {
        await Task.Run(action); //I expected the exception to be unwrapped and thrown here
    }
}
```

For the curious ones a more realistic `OperationExecuter` would be something along the lines of:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Do();
        Do2();
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static async Task Do()
    {
        var service = new Service(new Hardware());
        try
        {
            await
                OperationExecuter.ExecuteAsync(service, handler => service.Operation1Completed += handler,
                    handler => service.Operation1Completed += handler, async () => await service.Operation1(),
                    CancellationToken.None);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            //Exception is caught!!!
        }
    }

    private static async Task Do2()
    {
        var service = new Service(new Hardware());
        try
        {
            await
                OperationExecuter.ExecuteAsync(service, handler => service.Operation1Completed += handler,
                    handler => service.Operation1Completed += handler, async () => await service.Operation2(60),
                    CancellationToken.None);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            //Exception is caught!!!
        }
    }
}

internal class OperationExecuter
{
    public static async Task ExecuteAsync(Service service, Action<EventHandler> subscriptionAction,
        Action<EventHandler> unsubscriptionAction, Func<Task> sendCommandAction, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var commandCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        var hardwareFailureCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        cancellationToken.Register(() => commandCompletionSource.SetCanceled());

        var eventHandler = new EventHandler((sender, args) =>
        {
            commandCompletionSource.SetResult(true);
        });

        service.HardwareFailure += (sender, args) => hardwareFailureCompletionSource.SetResult(false);

        subscriptionAction(eventHandler);

        try
        {
            await Task.Run(sendCommandAction, cancellationToken);
            await Task.WhenAny(commandCompletionSource.Task, hardwareFailureCompletionSource.Task);

            //same for disconnection, etc
            if (hardwareFailureCompletionSource.Task.IsCompleted)
            {
                throw new HardwareFailureException();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            unsubscriptionAction(eventHandler);
        }
    }
}

class HardwareFailureException : Exception
{
}

class Service
{
    private readonly Hardware hardware;

    public Service(Hardware hardware)
    {
        this.hardware = hardware;
    }

    public async Task Operation1() //something like sending command to hardware
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    public event EventHandler Operation1Completed;

    public async Task Operation2(int someParameter)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    public event EventHandler Operation2Completed;

    public event EventHandler LostConnection;

    public event EventHandler HardwareFailure;
}

class Hardware
{
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that you actually create a `Task<Task>`, and you only `await` the outter `Task`. This is one of the reasons as to why you shouldn't be using the `Task` constructor. Instead, use `Task.Run`, which is aware of that and will unwrap the outter task for you:

```
private static async Task Do()
{
    var task = Task.Run(async() => await Operation());
    try
    {
        await OperationExecuter.ExecuteAsync(task);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        //I expected the exception to be caught here
    }
}
```

**Edit**:

@Servy points out correctly that, unless *there is a particular good reason* you're wrapping your `Task` with `Task.Run`, you can save that all together and simply `await` on the created `Task` and save yourself the unwrapping trouble all together:

```
public class OperationExecuter
{
    public static async Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> func)
    {
        await func();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is important that the `OperationExecuter` has control of when to start the task. I guess I should really have the `OperationExecuter` take an action and use `Task.Run(action)` then, correct?

Comment: Then you should change your implementation. You shouldn't be passing around cold tasks. For example, using `Task.Start` twice would yield an exception, and is also against the guidelines. Instead, you could queue delegates to your `OperationExecutor` and have it use `Task.Run` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately changing the implementation so that `OperationExecuter` takes an `Action` instead and using `Task.Run` yields to  same result.

Comment: @Joao That's because `Action` coverts to `async void`. You need to accept a `Func<Task>`

Comment: Rather than  unwrapping the unnecessarily wrapped task, you should just *not unnecessarily wrap the `Task` in the first place*.  Calling `Task.Run` on a `Task` returning method just so it can create a new task and then immediately unwrap it is just confusing and wasteful.  Just call the method an remove the wrapping entirely.

Comment: There's also no need for `ExecuteAsync` to be an `async` method.  You can just remove that and have the body be `return func();`  Or, for that matter, just get rid of the method and have the caller lnvoke the delegate when they want to instead of making a method just to invoke a delegate.

Comment: @Servy You could, but for some reason his executor needs to control the invocations.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I don't see any reason for it to.  It looks like he just thought that it needed to do more than it *actually* needs to do, when in reality I see no need for it to exist at all.

Comment: @Servy I dont either, but you never know.. OP?

Comment: @JoaoMilasch See earlier comments.

Comment: @Servy Like I said in the OP, the code is oversimplified for the sake of isolating the problem, which makes it seem completely useless. The what I'm calling here `OperationExecuter` essentially, in the actual project code takes an event subscription action, an event unsubscription action, cancellation token and uses `TaskCompletionSource`s to monitor for that event along with other common failure events. I'm updating my question with a more realistic example.

Comment: I am under the impression that exceptions in Tasks don't get caught by `try` blocks. Don't you have to examine one of the tasks's properties to see any exceptions the task itself threw?

Comment: @ErikE `await` unwraps aggregate exceptions in the task object. Try it, it is beautiful

Comment: @Servy yes, I understand it now. No need to call task.run.